# DexieJS how to get all from a table?

Tags: dexie

After a week of searching and trying, i still cannot find a way to get all records from a table. i know, feel free to shout at me. But the app still have to be working so I have to workaround it. I use the following code and i have no doubt it is the worst possible way.

```
db.table.orderBy('id').toArray().then( async result => {
  await result.reduce( (promise, item) => { 
    await promise;
    console.log(item);
    // coding here
  } );
});
```

Yes, that is my workaround, hate me. i hate myself for that too.

Please advice, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
db.table.toArray().then(items => console.log(items));
```